# Multi column combo box in Kendo for Angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to create multi-column combo-box in Kendo-Angular 2.I can't find it in the documentation: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/ Is this option present in the Kendo support for Angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

The MultiSelect component provides [numerous templates](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/templates/), which could be used to control the rendering of the header, footer and the item content. That being said, we can easily achieve different layout using some additional styling.

```
<kendo-multiselect
    [data]="listItems"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [textField]="'text'"
    [valueField]="'value'"
  >
  <ng-template kendoMultiSelectHeaderTemplate>
    <div class="dropdown-header k-widget k-header">
      <span>Value</span>
      <span>Text</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    <span class="k-state-default"><h3>{{dataItem.value}}</h3></span>
    <span class="k-state-default"><h3>{{dataItem.text}}</h3></span>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-multiselect>
```

Here is a plunker that demonstrates the templates usage:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BvdyXuQ4TQ5OFwDliqYd?p=preview

Please note, that the component doesn't have table-like layout and you will need to implement it manually. Nevertheless as it is shown in the demo, this shouldn't be a tough task.

Comment: For the case you want to have multiple options in one row (maybe he meant that) then just put 'float: left;' to the class 'k-item'.

Comment: I'm not sure. I hope @A_j will comment on his idea. As to the layout of placing multiple items on the same row, I would say that it won't work flawlessly. The keyboard navigation won't work as expected and it'll look like a bug. I would suggest keeping the layout unchanged and design a new custom component if needed.

Comment: (4 years later) Author asks about MultiColumnComboBox, not MultiSelect. You can now find an official MultiColumnComboBox Component in the Kendo for Angular library. Documentation about this component is available [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multicolumncombobox/)